# Adding values of 2 columns based on a condition

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dfs:

df1

```
      'TOM'    'MIKE'  'DISTANCE'
'A'     5         7         2
'B'     4         5         9
'C'     3         3         0
```

df2

```
      'LAURA'    'LISA'  'DISTANCE'
'A'     4           3        0
'B'     4           3        9 
'C'     1           2        3
```

I have concat them together with axis=1 , however I would like to join the column `DISTANCE` into 1 by adding the values of df2.DISTANCE only when the value in df1.DISTANCE is 0.

The desired output would be:

df3

```
      'TOM'    'MIKE'  'DISTANCE'   'LAURA'   'LISA'
'A'     5         7         2         4         3
'B'     4         5         9         4         3
'C'     3         3         3         1         2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the two dataframes together so we can specify a `rsuffix` so we can distinguish the two `DISTANCE` columns from both dataframes.

Then we use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to replace the `0` from the first dataframe with the distance from the 2nd dataframe:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, rsuffix='_2')
df3['DISTANCE'] = np.where(df3['DISTANCE'].eq(0), df3['DISTANCE_2'], df3['DISTANCE'])
df3 = df3.drop(columns=['DISTANCE_2'])
```

**Output**

```
   TOM  MIKE  DISTANCE  LAURA  LISA
0    5     7         2      4     3
1    4     5         9      4     3
2    3     3         3      1     2
```

---

Or we can use `.loc` to replace the values:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, rsuffix='_2')
df3.loc[df3['DISTANCE'].eq(0), 'DISTANCE'] = df3['DISTANCE_2']
df3 = df3.drop(columns=['DISTANCE_2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `combine_first` a try

```
df1["'DISTANCE'"].mask(df1["'DISTANCE'"].eq(0),inplace=True)
df=df1.combine_first(df2)
df
     'DISTANCE'  'LAURA'  'LISA'  'MIKE'  'TOM'
'A'         2.0      4.0     3.0       7      5
'B'         9.0      4.0     3.0       5      4
'C'         3.0      1.0     2.0       3      3
```